# Change Python for loop range (higher limit) at runtime

Tags: python, for-loop, runtime, variable-assignment

How do I change the higher limit of a python  for loop at runtime?

The code,

```
from random import randint

lower_limit = 0
higher_limit = 200
step_size = 5

for i in range(lower_limit, higher_limit, step_size):
    # do something

    higher_limit = higher_limit + randint(0, 5)
```

The code runs till the first higher limit and doesn't care about the declared one, What can be done to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a range once it is created. I think it would be easier for you to restructure your logic and replace `range` with `while`:

```
lower_limit = 0
higher_limit = 200
step_size = 5
i = 0

while lower_limit <= i < higher_limit:
    # do something

    i = i + step_size

    higher_limit = higher_limit + randint(0, 5)
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to use while:

```
from random import randint

lower_limit = 0
higher_limit = 200
step_size = 5

while i <higher_limit:
    # do something

    higher_limit = higher_limit + randint(0, 5)
    i += 5
```

Comment: Thanks I haven't noticed that. I changed it :)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can define your own version of range (simplified):

```
from random import randint

def higher_range(start, upto, step, inc):
    i = start
    while i < upto:
        yield i
        i += step
        upto += randint(0, inc)

for j in higher_range(0, 10, 5, 5):
    print j
```

Obviously, there is not guarantee it will terminate any time soon...